# I face a problem about using prepared database in Android room

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am attempting to implement Room in my Android application, but am getting the error
[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0yom.png) 
I find that the the found part for member_id is Integer while expected part is INTEGER, but I don't know how to set it and don't understand what is the different between this two.
This is the table in my database
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub57a.png)
this is my Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "Hierarchy")
public class Hierarchy {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @NotNull private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "catagory_id")
    @NotNull private Integer catagory_Id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "member_id")
    @NotNull private int member_id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Integer getCatagory_Id() {
        return catagory_Id;
    }

    public void setCatagory_Id(@NotNull Integer catagory_Id) {
        this.catagory_Id = catagory_Id;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Integer getMember_id() {
        return member_id;
    }

    public void setMember_id(@NotNull Integer member_id) {
        this.member_id = member_id;
    }
}
```

I create the database in this form

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, MyDataBase.class, "MedicineData.db")
                .createFromAsset("Database/dataset.db")
                .build();
    }
```

Thank you very much for help me!

I tried to change the int to Integer in entity but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the found, the pre-packaged/asset database, you have **category_id**, on the expected i.e. the `@Entity` annotated Hierarchy class you have **catagory_id**

i.e. an **a** rather than an **e** for the fourth character.

So probably change to use:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "Hierarchy")
public class Hierarchy {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @NotNull private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id") /*<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED 4th character to e*/
    @NotNull private Integer catagory_Id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "member_id")
    @NotNull private int member_id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Integer getCatagory_Id() {
        return catagory_Id;
    }

    public void setCatagory_Id(@NotNull Integer catagory_Id) {
        this.catagory_Id = catagory_Id;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Integer getMember_id() {
        return member_id;
    }

    public void setMember_id(@NotNull Integer member_id) {
        this.member_id = member_id;
    }
}
```

You may wish to also change all uses of catagory to category.